# Javascript - *element*.style.display = 'none' not hiding the element

Tags: javascript, html

I am running a wordpress website with a html form. When I change one field, I want another field to be hidden. This was working and I don't know what I changed but it seems to have stopped working.

```js
function updateLitres()
{
    document.getElementById("litres").style.display = 'none';
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="dollars" name="dollars" min="0" max="1000" onkeyup="updateLitres()">
<input type="number" id="litres" name="litres" min="0" max="5000">
```

Thanks

Comment: Any errors in the web console?

Comment: Your code is working correctly as you can see in the code snippet. The problem will be specific to your site. My guess is CORS _unsafe-inline_ policy.

Comment: @Jax-p - Good point! (I think you meant CSP rather than CORS).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes, I meant [CSP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP), my bad. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Jax-p - Typo or not, it was still a really good observation. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks - I did not think to check the web console.. It had an error where I was trying to change the value of an element which did not exist (left over from old code). I removed this and it all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had an error where I was trying to change the value of an element which did not exist "unable to change value of null". I removed this line and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of five reasons that might not work, one or two of which will give you an error in the web console, the other three of which won't:

1. The `id="litres"` element doesn't exist as of when `updateLitres` is called (will result in an error message in the console). You can check for this by looking in the web console for an error message about using `style` on `null`.
2. There is more than one `id="litres"` element in the document, and you're looking at the second or later (the code will hide the first). You can check for this by looking at the result of `document.querySelectorAll("[id=litres]").length` and/or by right-clicking the element, choosing Inspect (or similar), and looking at whether you see the style change. (Note: Having multiple elements with the same `id` value is invalid. If this is the problem, the solution is to use a class instead, and select the right one of the multiple possible elements with that class.)
3. There is a high-specificity rule in your CSS that makes the `id="litres"` visible (for instance, `#litres { display: inline !important; }`. You can check for this by right-clicking the element, choosing Inspect (or similar), and looking at the CSS being applied to it.
4. You're not calling`updateLitres` at all. You can check for this by putting a breakpoint on the statement within it and seeing if the breakpoint is ever reached. (But see also #5.)
5. The page is being served with a `Content-Security-Policy` header, which disallows inline script by default; [more here](https://content-security-policy.com/examples/allow-inline-script/). This should show up as an error or warning in the web console.

Answer (score -3):

```js
const $dollars = document.getElementById(`dollars`);
const $litres = document.getElementById(`litres`);


$dollars.addEventListener(`change`, e => {
  $litres.hidden = true;
});
```

```html
<input type="number" id="dollars" name="dollars" min="0" max="1000" placeholder="dollars">
<input type="number" id="litres" name="litres" min="0" max="5000" placeholder="litres">
```